# Syncing forked repo with upstream/master or upstream/develop?

Tags: git, github

I forked a repo by following the directions on [this](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/) link. Now I am trying to sync my fork because it is something like 50 commits behind. I have seen the instructions [here](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/). I want to make changes ONLY to my local forked version but would like to continue to update my local forked version by pulling from the original version. My forked repo and the original repo have the default branch as 'develop'. When I write 'git branch', I get * develop

Does that mean I should be doing

```
git merge upstream/develop
```

instead of the instructed

```
git merge upstream/master
```

in order to pull the changes to my local version?

In order to push changes to my local copy only but update github would I would just use

```
git push origin/develop
```

?

Sorry, this is such an noob question laid out by the tutorials but I am really nervous about messing up the original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, git merge upstream/develop should work: you can check that by doing a `git branch -avvv` after the `git fetch upstream` step: you should see `upstream/develop` listed as a remote branch.

> In order to push changes to my local copy only but update github would I would just use `git push origin/develop`

It would be:

```
git push origin develop
```